# Stackoverflow как писать - чтобы все не сбивалось в одну строчку

Tags: поддержка, редактор, форматирование

Изначально я вопрос пишу в Notepad++ в кодировке UTF-8.
В Notepad++ все выглядит красиво.
Затем, в браузере IE или Firefox оформляю вопрос.

И все сбивается в одну строчку после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить вопрос".
Подскажите, как правильно нужно делать, чтобы этого не происходило?

Comment: пустая строка между абзацами

Comment: В правом верхнем углу поля ввода вопроса-ответа есть круглый значок со знаком вопроса: нажмите на него. Появится справка. Если её недостаточно, нажмите пункт "Расширенная справка"

Answer (score 10):

Ну, обо всем по порядку.

Язык разметки, который использует редактор Stack Overflow, называется [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). Он достаточно популярен, если введете название в поисковик, то найдете достаточно информации.

Кроме того, в самом редакторе Stack Overflow, есть встроенная справка по Markdown.
Нажмите на знак вопроса в правом верхнем углу:

[image: Справка]

и он покажет Вам список подсказок по оформлению и ссылку на расширенную [справку о редакторе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Многие вопросы после этого отпадут.

Еще на Stack Overflow есть возможность просматривать исходный код постов других участников. Если видите хорошее оформление в чужом вопросе или ответе, то можете нажать кнопку «править» под ним и посмотреть как это работает. Править пост после этого не обязательно.

Для многих текстовых редакторов есть плагины, которые упрощают работу с Markdown.
Notepad++ не исключение. Скачайте и установите [MarkdownViewerPlusPlus](https://github.com/nea/MarkdownViewerPlusPlus) и на главной панели появится кнопка [image: иконка Markdown] по нажатию на которую появится панель предварительного просмотра:

[image: окно Notepad++ с панелью предварительного просмотра Markdown]

Answer (score 6):

Когда вы хотите так:

> Первая строка
> Вторая строка

окончите первую строку **двумя** пробелами (и клавишем <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

---

Когда вы хотите так:

> Первый абзац
>
> Второй абзац

окончите первый абзац **двумя** клавишами <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Пробую делать как вы сказали.  
Но после нажатия клавиши Enter у меня сразу происходит отправка коментария.  
И я не могу написать в несколько строк.  
Я пишу в npp - после каждой строки ставлю два пробела.  
Переношу в браузер с помощью copy paste.
Но всеравно все сбивается в одну строку.

Comment: Я это сделал прямо с вашим вопросом, когда я его исправил — результат вы можете видеть.

Comment: Да проверил в вопросе это работает. Спасибо большое. Может за одно подскажете как сделать много строчный комментарий?

Comment: Notepad++ наверно удалил лишние пробелы в конце строк.

Comment: Многострочный комментарий сделать нельзя.

Comment: Когда вам мой ответ помог, нажмите, пожалуйста, на галочку возле него и / или на треугольную стрелку вверх.