# Есть ли какой-нибудь внешний редактор текста для Stackoverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, редактор

Есть ли какой нибудь редактор текста для stackoverflow, в котором можно было бы набрать вопрос, а потом перенести его уже на этот портал? Уж очень много времени занимает верстка текста для stackoverflow.

Comment: Использовать тот, что поддерживает Markdown

Comment: ну не долго - скопировал вставил - сохранил и всё

Comment: Пока выставишь абзацы, пока найдешь как сделать заголовки в тексте, потом добавить код тоже надо правильно
Занимает кучу времени
У меня большинство коллег перестали отвечать на вопросы из за этого

Comment: Вот сообщение выше, по абзацам не выстроилось

Comment: Что за бред, все тут просто и быстро правится. Просто видимо кто-то не читает справку и по этому для него кажется это не возможным или очень долгим, раз прочитал и забыл, оно само откладывается..

Comment: And, я посмотрел ваши вопросы, они тоже не отформатированы, максимум выделен код и вставлены разрывы между строк, это костыли. Я же спрашиваю про то как правильно форматировать и есть ли инструмент упрощающий это.

Comment: «Разрывы между строк» — это не костыли, а единственно правильный способ создания абзацев. Изучите Markdown, он нетрудный.

Comment: andreymal, а как же отступ? «Разрывы между строк» - пуста строка в тексте, следующий текст без отступ, что это такое, если не костыль?

Comment: @EfimoffN в отступах нет никакого смысла. Пустой строки более чем достаточно для обозначения абзаца.

Comment: @andreymal отступ оформляет текст, делает его более читабельным. Разрыв же настраивает читателя на то, что следующая часть текста будет отдельной главой

Comment: @EfimoffN главы отделяются не разрывом, а заголовками, или по крайней мере тремя звёздочками. Откройте любую бумажную книгу — вы там никогда не увидите разделения глав пустой строкой.

Comment: @EfimoffN если вам очень хочется видеть костыли из бумажных книг здесь, вы можете подключить к своему браузеру пользовательский стиль и для элемента `p` убрать `margin` и добавить `text-indent`, чтобы тексты стали выглядеть примерно так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOeBa.png

Comment: @andreymal мы там вообще не увидим замену абзацев пустыми строками.

Comment: @EfimoffN потому что это костыль для экономии бумаги. В веб-сайтах бумаги нет и экономить нечего — поэтому подавляющее большинство веб-сайтов не используют никаких отступов и делят абзацы пустыми строками. И это хорошо и правильно, не надо тащить в веб костыли из бумажных книг.

Comment: @EfimoffN подробнее можно почитать например тут https://designpub.ru/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-43d58f822cec

Comment: @andreymal довольно интересно, но как это поможет редактировать текст на данном портале?

Comment: @andreymal изначально вопрос был другой, есть ли редактор для этого портала, что бы не использовать костыли (имею в вид спец символы)

Comment: @andreymal - _единственно правильный способ создания абзацев_ - нет. В типографике правильный способ - отступы. В книгах используют именно их. То, что на этом сайте и повмесестно в интернете используют разрывы - это от низкой квалификации верстальщиков.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov и вы тоже почитайте эту ссылку и поймите свою неправоту https://designpub.ru/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-43d58f822cec

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov и если «низкая квалификация» даёт более красивый, удобный и читабельный текст — я как читатель предпочту «низкую квалификацию».

Comment: @andreymal - ещё раз: _единственно правильный способ_ - нет, не единственный. Способы есть разные. Я не говорю, что обязательно нужно использовать отступы или обязательно разрывы. Я говорю, что это не единственный способ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в Markdown это именно что единственно правильный способ просто по синтаксису языка, другого способа просто нет технически. (Ну ладно, есть ещё `<p>`, но это уже не Markdown)

Comment: @andreymal - _другого способа просто нет технически_ - это как раз означает низкую квалификацию тех, кто не подумал о других возможных способах.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Markdown задаёт *разметку*, а не внешний вид, не путайте эти две вещи. Иметь несколько способов обозначения абзацев в *разметке* — это бессмысленное переусложнение. А задать внешний вид размеченным абзацам можно как угодно с помощью стилей.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вот вам кстати демонстрация работы стилей https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_0KU2xJMsw

Comment: Но вообще это всё всё равно не по теме вопроса. Посоветуйте кто-нибудь автору WYSIWYG-редактор с Markdown, я таких не знаю)

Comment: Ага, давайте из стека сделаем блог, с оформлением страницек, стилистикой, да что уж тут говорить, напишем для таких как вы, специально редактор, чтобы там можно было в разных стилях писать текст! САРКАЗМ!

Comment: @And ну, я примерно такое делал на одном из своих сайтов :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvhIU.gif

Comment: @EfimoffN, нету тут нормального форматера (про форматирование в комментариях я вообще молчу)

Comment: @avp, комментарии и не предназначены для больших блоков текста, которым нужно специальное форматирование, а общее (в виде выделения курсивом и полужирным, а также ссылки) работает - этого  ̶х̶в̶а̶т̶и̶т̶ ̶в̶с̶е̶м̶ достаточно

Comment: Посмотрите [Stackoverflow как писать - чтобы все не сбивалось в одну строчку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9398) и [Оформление текста в StackOverlow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3145). Может поможет

Comment: @Grundy, у меня давно уже сложилось впечатление, что не все тут для удобства (и удовольствия)  людей... (но, как говорится, за неимением гербовой, пишем на простой)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант, [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) с расширением [Docs Markdown](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs-authoring/tree/master/docs-markdown). Оно заточено под Microsoft Docs, но и для Stackoverflow подойдет. Поддерживается подсветка синтаксиса, форматирование через команды меню и предпросмотр.

Например, чтобы выделить фрагмент кода, нажимаем Alt+M для вызова меню:

[image: vscode menu]

В меню выбираем **Code**, указываем язык, и фрагмент будет выделен с помощью Code fence (```).

Для предпросмотра в меню выбираем Preview, тогда результат отрисовки Markdown отобразится в правой части окна:

[image: vscode]

Не то, чтобы было сильно много функционала по сравнению со встроенным редактором, но может вам поможет.

Comment: А ежели к примеру автор на линухе?

Comment: @Victor, тогда что?

Comment: @Андрей NOP VS Code? On Linux?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, ну в ответе есть же ссылка, вы открывали ее?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, VS Code работает под Linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Comment: @insolor Да? Не знал, спасибо.